# How do I tell Ubuntu to search a different path for drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, amd-graphics, opengl

Trying to get Blender/Steam to render with my AMD GPU, have finally gotten it to install the `amdgpu-pro` drivers so it's recognized inside of Blender/Steam.

But it's looking in the wrong path for my drivers;

`glxgears`

---

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  46
  Current serial number in output stream:  45
```

It looks like it's looking in `/snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri` for my drivers. But if I run the following command;

`locate swrast`

---

```
/snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
/snap/alacritty/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

It seems like it should be looking in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri`

Also `dpkg -l | grep radeonsi` returns nothing.

**How do I tell my system to look in the correct directory?**